# Id:Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am attempting to test deploy an application which is made in unity using vuforia. The application developed in unity, is then built for IOS. This then provides an xcode file which then needs to be built. The building process works fine, however when it starts linking the app to the device this error pops up [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQbxz.jpg) which after more research i found this which goes in a bit more detail [Detailed Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTGrc.jpg). The versions are the following : **Xcode** - 8.3.3 **Unity** - 2017.1.0f3 **Vuforia** - V5.5.9
If any more information is needed to make the problem clearer let me know. Any Ideas please? and thank you all in advance.

Comment: It would be helpfull to add the referenced errors in text format. This way it will be easier and faster to see what went wrong (and the images are kinda hart to read)

Comment: Un Defined symbols for architecture arm 7:

Comment: "_unityRenderBufferMTLTexture", referenced from: PlatformiOS::setRenderBuffers(void*) in libVuforiaUnityPlayer.a(PlatformiOS.o) "_UnityCurrentMTLCommandEncoder", referenced from: PlatformiOS::setRenderBuffers(void*)in libVuforia Unity Player.a(PlatformiOS.o) id:symbol(s) found for architecture arm7 clang:error linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see

Comment: sorry about the formating